# Spring AMQP Inbound Adapter with empty queue name

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm developing a consumer application using [Spring AMQP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/) that receives messages from RabbitMQ. There is a topic exchange declared. To connect to Rabbit I create a queue with an empty name, because **the broker will provide an automatic queue name**, see the [InterCor M4 Upgraded Specifications Hybrid specifications](https://intercor-project.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/15/2019/01/InterCor_M4-Upgraded-Specifications-Hybrid_v2.1-final_INEA.pdf#page=35):

```
@Bean
public TopicExchange exchange() {
    TopicExchange topicExchange = new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
    topicExchange.setShouldDeclare(false);
    return topicExchange;
}

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
  return new Queue("", queueDurable, queueExclusive, queueAutoDelete, queueParameters);
}

@Bean
public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
}
```

But when I try to configure an [AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_2) using the Spring Integration Java DSL:

```
@Autowired
private Queue queue;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, queue))
      .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
      .get();
}
```

I get an error **'queueName' cannot be null or empty**

```
2018-05-25 13:39:15.080 ERROR 14636 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'queueName' cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:276) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:337) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

How can I set a value of the message queue name to an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AMQP-816](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-816) issue has been fixed and now is available in Spring Boot [2.1.0](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-boot-2-1-0).

Updating the parent of the project fixes the issue:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

### Empty queue name

```
spring:
    rabbitmq:
        queue:
            name:
            durable: false
            exclusive: true
            autoDelete: true
```

creates an automatic queue name **amq.gen-U1vKiSfIvy8bO11jLD29Sw**:

<kbd>[image: Empty queue name]</kbd>

### Non-empty queue name

```
spring:
    rabbitmq:
        queue:
            name: abc
            durable: false
            exclusive: true
            autoDelete: true
```

creates a queue named **abc**:

<kbd>[image: Non-empty queue name]</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

That is not a good solution.

The problem is that with a broker-generated queue name, if the connection is lost and re-established, the queue name will change, but the container won't know about the new queue and will try to consume from the old one.

`AnonymousQueue` solves this problem by the framework generating the random name.

But, anonymous queues are not durable, are exclusive and are auto-delete.

If you want a Queue with different properties to that, but still want a random name, use

```
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
  return new Queue(new AnonymousQueue.Base64UrlNamingStrategy().generateName(),
      queueDurable, queueExclusive, queueAutoDelete, queueParameters);
}
```

That way, if the connection is lost and re-established, the queue will get the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, but here I have to comply with the specs which mandate the empty name. It's been adopted by a wider community and we can't change it. I tried to replace `Amqp.inboundAdapter` with a [RabbitMQ message receiver](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#initial) and set it as a Message Listener, but still get exactly the same exception. Looks like will have to use a Java Client unfortunately.

Comment: I think I've come up with a way to support this use case; feel free to open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Raised an improvement Jira issue [AMQP-816](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-816).

Comment: @GaryRussell Is it possible to have Server-Generated names (https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#server-named-queues) here? I get something like `spring.gen-WG2oKXZlSSuOc6m9uJyZ0g` if left blank, but I have no privileges to do this (only server generated names are allowed on this rabbit I use).

Comment: Don’t ask questions in comments, especially on 4 year old answers. The framework now supports broker named queues https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/commit/b40019ba720578cd056fbedd9b46e13a11f21dd7 See the accepted answer.

Comment: If you are having problems, ask a new question showing code and config.